# How could I split a String into an array in Kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, string, kotlin

I need to split a String read in from a file into an array of values. I want to split the String at the commas, so for example, if the String read:

```
"name, 2012, 2017"
```

The values in the array would be:

- array index 0 - name
- array index 1 - 2012
- array index 2 - 2017

I found this example in Java:

```
String[] stringArray = string.split(",");
```

How I could do it in Kotlin?

Comment: Just so you know if you have Java code and a Kotlin file open (in IntelliJ/AndroidStudio) and paste it IntelliJ will offer you to auto convert that code to Kotlin.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
val strs = "name, 2012, 2017".split(",").toTypedArray()
```

Comment: This answer isn't correct. Kotlin's `split` method will return a List not an array.

Comment: In which case you can write: `val strs = "name, 2012, 2017".split(",").toTypedArray()`

Comment: Java's `split` method actually uses an `ArrayList` internally so the end result is the same

Answer (score 21):

Simple as it is:

```
val string: String = "leo_Ana_John"
val yourArray: List<String> = string.split("_")
```

you get: yourArray[0] == leo, yourArray[1] == Ana, yourArray[2]==John

In this case, just change the "_" from my code to ", " of yours. Se bellow

```
    val yourArray: List<String> = string.split(", ")
```

Answer (score 17):

If we have a string of values that splited by any character like ",":

```
 val values = "Name1 ,Name2, Name3" // Read List from somewhere
 val lstValues: List<String> = values.split(",").map { it -> it.trim() }
 lstValues.forEach { it ->
                Log.i("Values", "value=$it")
                //Do Something
            }
```

It's better to use  trim() to delete spaces around strings if exist.
Consider that if have a  "," at the end of string it makes one null item, so can check it  with this code before split :

```
 if ( values.endsWith(",") )
     values = values.substring(0, values.length - 1)
```

if you want to convert list to Array ,use this code:

```
      var  arr = lstValues.toTypedArray()
      arr.forEach {  Log.i("ArrayItem", " Array item=" + it ) }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var newStrg= "853 kB"
val mString = newStrg!!.split(" ").toTypedArray()
```

Here Split parameter is **space**

```
mString[0] = "853"
mString[1] = "kB"
```

Comment: `!!` in `newStrg!!` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Split a string using inbuilt split method then using method extensions isNum() to return numeric or not.

```
fun String.isNum(): Boolean{
   var num:Int? = this.trim().toIntOrNull()
   return if (num != null) true else false
}

for (x in "name, 2012, 2017".split(",")) {
   println(x.isNum())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple/several delimiters in kotlin `split`, you need to pass them separately:

```
 val validUrl = "http://test.com/</a> -".split(">", " ", "<").first()
```