# How to split a string seperated where characters are seperated by , to array in kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-studio, kotlin

```
val sharedPreferences90 = 
       getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs90", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
   
val savedString90: String? = 
    sharedPreferences90.getString("STRING90","null") `
```

Here my String is `company1,company2,company3`. I would like to convert it to array. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I split a String into an array in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038476/how-could-i-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

```
val result = "company1,company2,company3".split(",").toTypedArray()
```